# How to correctly store an array of RegEx values in a JSON file and retrive it from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, gulp, purge

I have the following array variable in a Javascript file, meant to be passed to [Purgecss for its `whitelistPatterns` option](https://www.purgecss.com/whitelisting#patterns) (please note that I'm specifically using it from the [`gulp-purgecss` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-purgecss)):

```js
var purgeWLP = [
    /^carousel-item.*/,    
    /collapsing/,           
    /show/,                
];
```

Now I want to store this and other project variables in an external `.json` file, meant to be accessed from various places and files; I've tried with the following code:

```
{
    "wlp": [
        "/^carousel-item.*/",
        "/collapsing/",
        "/show/"
    ]
}
```

But I'm experiencing errors and not getting what I expect, namely the same exact results as with the `purgeWLP` variable in the javascript file.

**How can I correctly store an array of regex values inside a `.json` file and retrieve it from Javascript?**

Answer (score 5):

Store them as strings without the slashes, and convert them back to RegExp objects after parsing the JSON string:

```js
const json = `{
    "wlp": [
        "^carousel-item.*",
        "collapsing",
        "show"
    ]
}`

const wlp = JSON.parse(json).wlp // or const wlp = require('./project.json').wlp on nodejs
  .map(str => new RegExp(str))

console.log(wlp)
```

And to save them you can use `JSON.stringify()` and map each RegExp object to its source string (see this [comment by Emanuel Vintilă](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603948/how-to-correctly-store-an-array-of-regex-values-in-a-json-file-and-retrive-it-fr/59603987?noredirect=1#comment105371861_59603987)):

```js
var purgeWLP = [
    /^carousel-item.*/,    
    /collapsing/,           
    /show/,                
];

var result = JSON.stringify(purgeWLP.map(re => re.source));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: And if you want to save them, `JSON.stringify(wlp.map(re => re.source))`

Comment: Word of caution, make sure backslashes are escaped correctly. `new RegExp("\\s")` not `new RegExp("\s")`.

Comment: Good point @ggorlen, and this is a nice answer that explains how to it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/5157454. btw - strings from `Regex.source` are escaped.

Comment: Thank you, this works if I store the JSON object inside the Javascript file, like in your example; but if i try to get the array from an actual external `.json` (imported with `const project = require('./config/project.json');`, I get an Unexpected token error.

Comment: Use a JSON validator like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to find the error in your file.

Comment: I solved by using `const wlp = require('./config/project.json').wlp` instead of `const wlp = JSON.parse(json).wlp` as you suggested. It now works fine.

Comment: I missed that you are working on nodejs (gulp). Requiring a JSON file parses it automatically.